# How to implement `From` for `Either` in Rust

Tags: rust, either

I have `Either` type:

```rust
enum Either<L, R> {
  Left(L),
  Right(R),
}
```

and i want to implement `From` trait for both of it's variants:

```rust
impl<L, R> From<L> for Either<L, R> {
    fn from(l: L) -> Self {
        Self::Left(l)
    }
}
impl<L, R> From<R> for Either<L, R> {
    fn from(r: R) -> Self {
        Self::Right(r)
    }
}
```

and yes, obviously they overlaps. So the question is how to make `Either`'s `L` and `R` generic types not equal and implement both `From`s? So that:

```rust
type EitherStringString = Either<String, String>; // compilation error, because `Either`'s `L` and `R` types are equal
```

```rust
type EitherStringInt = Either<String, i32>; // ok
```

```rust
#[test]
fn either_string_int_from_string() { // ok
  let string: String = String::from("hello");
  assert_eq!(
    Either::<String, i32>::Left(string),
    string.into()
  );
}
#[test]
fn either_string_int_from_int() { // ok
  let number: i32 = 42;
  assert_eq!(
    Either::<String, i32>::Right(number),
    number.into()
  );
}
```

"Prior art": `negative_bounds` and `negative_impls` features looks like this is the exact thing i need, but i can't figure out how to use them to achieve desired result. I tried:

```rust
#![feature(negative_bounds, negative_impls)]

trait LT {}
trait RT: !LT {}

// neither combination of this solves the issue
// impl<L: !RT> LT for L {}
// impl<L> !RT for L {}
// impl<R: !LT> RT for R {}
// impl<R> !LT for R {}

impl<L: LT, R: RT> From<L> for Either<L, R> {
    fn from(l: L) -> Self {
        Self::Left(l)
    }
}
impl<L: LT, R: RT> From<R> for Either<L, R> {
    fn from(r: R) -> Self {
        Self::Right(r)
    }
}
```

but this gives compilation error:

```
conflicting implementations of trait `From<_>` for type `either::Either<_, _>`
```

So how to implement `From` for `Either`?

Comment: You can use one _newtype_ for each side of `Either` such as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f24b4081c1c2d9bf76e6e811c8034a0a). But I'm not sure that will be very useful. You can get a similar effect by writing `use Either::*;` unless you have some very specific generic code to solve.

Comment: @rodrigo, unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue of having to manually select and write Left or Right + this in no way prevents from creating `Either<T, T>`, which should be prohibited.

Comment: Creating `Either<T, T>` should not be prohibited. Ad-hoc restrictions and special casing of types like this is exactly why the concept of `void` creates such headaches in generic code in other languages, but doesn't in Rust: because in Rust, `()` is not special. Neither should `Either<T, T>` be special. Consider that anywhere a generic `Either<L, R>` exists, you will have to prove to the compiler that `L` and `R` are not the same type, which is both impractical in a lot of cases, as well as entirely pointless because there is no fundamental reason that type should not exist.